# how to select a group from groupby dataframe using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe with multilevel index (company, year) that grouped by mean, looks like this:

```
company  year  mean salary
ABC      2018     3000
         2019     3400
LOL      2018     1200
         2019     3500
```

I want to select the data belongs to "LOL", my desired outcome would be:

```
company  year  mean salary
LOL      2018     1200
         2019     3500
```

Is there a way I can only select a certain group? I tried to use .filter function on dataframe but I was only able to apply it to rows such as (lambda x: x > 1000) but not for index value.

Any advice will be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) with `drop_level=False` for avoid removed first level:

```
df1 = df.xs('LOL', drop_level=False)
```

Or filter by first level with [`Index.get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html):

```
df1 = df[df.index.get_level_values(0) == 'LOL']
```

---

```
print (df1)
              mean salary
company year             
LOL     2018         1200
        2019         3500
```